# Submit a form with an a link does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I have this form

```
<form method="POST" action="http://site.test/nodes/destroy" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" role="form"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="G2Mk8eZLwPOw5YYvKMSLj7kw6ThR4e2fP7aAWoGt">

    <a href="" onclick="form.submit();">
        <i class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i>
    </a>


    <input name="ip" type="hidden" value="172.18.29.241">

</form>
```

When I click the trash can it suppose to submnit the form, it does not.

I can see the page getting refresh, but it never reach my controller.

What did I miss ?

Comment: Try changing `href=""` to `href="#"`. And you may need `onclick="document.forms[0].submit();"` instead of what you have now.

Comment: okay, trying now.

Comment: Just to add, if I did this, it will works `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"> Delete </button>` - but the goal is to use the a tag.

Comment: Why not use a submit button and just style it to *look like* a link?  If you're using Bootstrap (the classes imply that you may be) then styling is trivial.

Comment: @j08691 : add `<a href="#" onclick="form.submit();">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i>
                                </a>` -- is not submit the form, and also flickering the page to the center, just click when you clicked on an `href="#" `

Comment: @David : Suggest that code -- please, because I would like to see that working.

Comment: @kyo: It's the same code you claimed worked in a previous comment, just with a different CSS class: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-link"> Delete </button>`  You can replace your `"Delete"` text with anything you like, including the `<i/>` element in your question.

Comment: To confirm, you should be using a button for this, not an anchor.  They have different *semantics*.

Comment: @David that works perfectly. You should answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, don't use a link (anchor) for this.  Doing so is causing you to try and write JavaScript code (and hacks such as `href="#"`) to try to fight the semantics of using a link when you should just be using a button.

Since you have Bootstrap, styling the button to *look like* a link is trivial.  For example:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
    <i class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i>
</button>
```

It keeps the HTML clean and simple, doesn't introduce unnecessary complexity, will work without JavaScript and is more accessible to tools like screen readers, and uses the semantics of the elements rather than fighting them.